# How to implement normal site registration/login together with social authentication(mainly facebook) in Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm a newbie in Django and I'm trying to port my vanilla php application to Python/Django. In my project, I want to let users authenticate using regular registration/login form or through social authentications like facebook, google and twitter.

I searched on google and stackoverflow for similar questions and came to know about django-social-auth, django-allauth, django-socialregistration etc. I tried django-allauth but failed to implement it properly resulting in lots of template syntax errors.

My questions are :

1) Which one should I choose for my requirements - regular + social authentication? Any live website where I can test it?

2) Which one is most used in live production sites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django-social-auth django-registration and django-profiles -- together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905088/django-social-auth-django-registration-and-django-profiles-together)

Answer (score 7):

[`django-social-auth`](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) is fantastic, has [a good support community](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/django-social-auth) and is very quick to set up. You can run it easily alongside regular auth and will also work nicely alongside [`django-registration`](http://code.google.com/p/django-registration/) and [`django-profiles`](http://code.google.com/p/django-profiles/) (I've used all 3 together before). [It also has a demo](http://social.matiasaguirre.net/).

It's also the most watched on Github when you compare it to the others on [django packages](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/authentication/landscape/) which is a good indication of it's popularity.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating separate packages can be a real pain. If you use django-allauth this work has already been done for you....

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon [this review](http://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/review-of-4-django-social-auth-apps/#django-social-auth) of four django social auth apps.

The top two are:

- django-allauth
- django-social-auth

At the time it was written, allauth had the lead but I believe (from looking at the github projects) that nowadays django-social-auth is more popular