# How do I configure Django to use python-social-auth for local logins?

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I can configure Django using social accounts for login, but I'd like to integrate local username/email and password login for those w/o a social account or for those who won't use one. I can use a third party tool like django-registration, but I'd rather not if python-social-auth supports this. Could anyone help w/an example of this or even point me to a place where one exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support it. You could switch to [`django-all-auth`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) which has both social and `django.contrib.auth` users but with `django-social-auth` you would need to integrate [`django-registration`](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home) or something similar ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905088/django-social-auth-django-registration-and-django-profiles-together) is an approach to getting the both working together - warning; it's an old answer)

Comment: I think it is because `python-social-auth` does support local logins
http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/index.html